# Symfony 4 api Restful No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, only for one resource

Tags: symfony, cors, symfony4, nelmiocorsbundle

I am using Symfony 4 as Restful API, I was working perfectly with calling the api from a VueJS application.
Today, I needed to add an another resource on the api but when I want to call it to get data from Vuejs I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". 
Only for this entity, for the others it's working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application
>   running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected
>   resources from a server at a different origin. A web application makes
>   a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a
>   different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin.

One of the possible solutions can be installing [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle). This will bring CORS handling directly to your application.

Another solution can be adding this header in your web server ([How do I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in NGINX?](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx)).

Comment: I am using NelmioCorsBundle:
But I don't understand why It is broked when I call the resource.
I added below the configuration I made.

Comment: I found the mistake; it's a code mistake. I thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Y.Coding what was it?

Comment: @Jalil I've just had the same problem and the solution in my case was to return a valid JSON. The error occured when I tried to `echo` some value followed by a `die` statement just to try things out.